# How do I add individual Custom styles to a new Word Tab in the Ribbon

Tags: vsto

We have created custom styles in Word 2010 and now want to add some of them as buttons to a custom tab in the Ribbon.

Using Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office, I have added new tabs and placed buttons using the idMSO values but can't see any way of adding individual custom styles we have created as I can't see any way of referencing their unique Control Names.

Am I doing this the right way (creating .dotm files with the tabs in xml) and how do I add buttons for individual styles rather than the Styles drop down menu.

thanks